# FoldLeft via FoldRight in Scala again

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fold

I know, this question has been asked already. But I have not understood any of the answers. I think I need a more graphic explanation. I can't understand how to "bridge" FoldLeft with FoldRight. 
I don't care if the anwer is not in Functional Programming in Scala.
Thabk you very much in advance.

Comment: What answers you don't understand? What *do* you understand of foldLeft and foldRight? What do you mean by "bridge"?

Comment: Not only has it been asked and answered already, but it was asked this morning, but that question seems to have been deleted. Odd. Anyway, you need to explain in what way the others are deficient for you, or this will get quickly closed as a duplicate. Either you are the same user who asked and deleted the other question or some course has set this as an assignment. In the latter case, you really should try something, and post when you are stuck

Comment: @pedrofurla, if it's like the other question, it's about implementing foldLeft in terms of foldRight (and vice versa)

Answer (score 1):

Just check how those are implemented:

```
  def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = {
    var result = z
    this foreach (x => result = op(result, x))
    result
  }

  def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B =
    reversed.foldLeft(z)((x, y) => op(y, x))
```

`foldLeft` traverses collection from left to right applying `op` to the `result` and current element, while `foldRight` traverses reversed collection (i.e. from right to left).

When `op` is symmetric and transitive `foldLeft` and `foldRight` are equivalent, for example:

```
List(1,2,3).foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
List(1,2,3).foldRight(0)(_ + _)
```

Result:

```
res0: Int = 6
res1: Int = 6
```

But otherwise `foldLeft` and `foldRight` may produce different results:

```
List(1,2,3).foldLeft(List[Int]()){case (list, el) => list :+ el }
List(1,2,3).foldRight(List[Int]()){case (el, list) => list :+ el }
```

Result:

```
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
res3: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: What I was trying to say is that I don't understand even what "Fold Left in the terms of Fold Right" means. I know how they work, but I don'r understand if foldleftviafoldright means to encapsulate one inside another of if it means that I use a Left To Right operation but using Fold Right.

Comment: Moreover, I dont know how to do that, well I know how to do it, but I don't understand it very well. Sorry for my wat of expression, I am not an english-speaker nor FP programmer.